# Postgres 13.9 - How to update nested json element value by appending two other json element values

Tags: json, postgresql

We are using Postgres 13.9 with the following table and json structures.

```
 CREATE TABLE eco_val (
        Client varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        eco_js json NULL
        CONSTRAINT pk_eco_val PRIMARY KEY (Client, ID)
    );
    
    insert into eco_val (Client,ID,eco_js) values ('testclient','7193497_1',
      '{"ecoOptions": [
        {
          "ecoValue": [
            {
              "name": "A",
              "locale": "en_US"
            }
          ],
          "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_1",
          "seq": 1,
          "defaultIndicator": false,
          "correctecoIndicator": false
        },
        {
          "ecoValue": [
            {
              "name": "1",
              "locale": "en_US"
            }
          ],
          "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_2",
          "seq": 2,
          "defaultIndicator": false,
          "correctecoIndicator": true
        },
        {
          "ecoValue": [
            {
              "name": "2",
              "locale": "en_US"
            }
          ],
          "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_1",
          "seq": 3,
          "defaultIndicator": false,
          "correctecoIndicator": true
        },
        {
          "ecoValue": [
            {
              "name": "5",
              "locale": "en_US"
            }
          ],
          "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_7",
          "seq": 4,
          "defaultIndicator": false,
          "correctecoIndicator": true
        },
        {
          "ecoValue": [
            {
              "name": "ab",
              "locale": "en_US"
            }
          ],
          "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_1",
          "seq": 5,
          "defaultIndicator": false,
          "correctecoIndicator": false
        },
        {
          "ecoValue": [
            {
              "name": "ad",
              "locale": "en_US"
            }
          ],
          "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_2",
          "seq": 6,
          "defaultIndicator": false,
          "correctecoIndicator": false
        }
      ]
    }');
```

Ideally, ecoOptionID should store a result of ID (i.e. 7193497_1) appended with an underscore and the **seq** that is right below it. Due to a bug in the application, the json got created with wrong values in ecoOptionID as shown in bold (for example 7193497_1_2 should have been 7193497_1_6 in the below table, 7193497_1_7 should have been 7193497_1_4) :

| id | ecooptionid | seq | cnt | last_digit_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7193497_1 | 7193497_1_1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 7193497_1 | **7193497_1_1** | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 7193497_1 | **7193497_1_1** | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 7193497_1 | 7193497_1_2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 7193497_1 | **7193497_1_2** | 6 | 2 | 2 |
| 7193497_1 | **7193497_1_7** | 4 | 1 | 7 |

```
select client,
    id, 
    ab ->>'ecoOptionID' ecoOptionID,
    ab ->>'seq' seq,
    count(*) over (partition by client,id,ab ->>'ecoOptionID' order by ab ->>'ecoOptionID') cnt,
 reverse(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ab ->>'ecoOptionID') FROM 1 for POSITION('_' IN REVERSE(ab ->>'ecoOptionID')) -1)) last_digit_id
    from
    eco_val a,
    jsonb_array_elements(eco_js::jsonb->'ecoOptions') ab
where
 id = '7193497_1';
```

We have a handful of data that needs to be corrected.

I've seen that jsonb_set can be used where the indexes or path are specified.
Unfortunately, the number of ecoOptionIDs in our JSON isnt predefined.

Is there a way to update all the ecoOptionIDs to be set to a string which is a concatenation of ID,underscore and seq of that element ?

The resultant JSON should look like this:

```
'{"ecoOptions": [
    {
      "ecoValue": [
        {
          "name": "A",
          "locale": "en_US"
        }
      ],
      "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_1",
      "seq": 1,
      "defaultIndicator": false,
      "correctecoIndicator": false
    },
    {
      "ecoValue": [
        {
          "name": "1",
          "locale": "en_US"
        }
      ],
      "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_2",
      "seq": 2,
      "defaultIndicator": false,
      "correctecoIndicator": true
    },
    {
      "ecoValue": [
        {
          "name": "2",
          "locale": "en_US"
        }
      ],
      "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_3",
      "seq": 3,
      "defaultIndicator": false,
      "correctecoIndicator": true
    },
    {
      "ecoValue": [
        {
          "name": "5",
          "locale": "en_US"
        }
      ],
      "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_4",
      "seq": 4,
      "defaultIndicator": false,
      "correctecoIndicator": true
    },
    {
      "ecoValue": [
        {
          "name": "ab",
          "locale": "en_US"
        }
      ],
      "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_5",
      "seq": 5,
      "defaultIndicator": false,
      "correctecoIndicator": false
    },
    {
      "ecoValue": [
        {
          "name": "ad",
          "locale": "en_US"
        }
      ],
      "ecoOptionID": "7193497_1_6",
      "seq": 6,
      "defaultIndicator": false,
      "correctecoIndicator": false
    }
  ]
}');
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to update multiple JSON keys with one PostgreSQL SELECT call.  You might be better off fixing the bug and re-inserting (or updating) the data

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution for this:

```
do $$
declare 
rec RECORD;
v_sql        varchar(3200);
begin for rec in
(select b.* from (select Client, t.rn-1 as ind,
    id, 
    t.account->>'ecoOptionID' ecoOptionID,
    t.account->>'seq' seq,
    count(*) over (partition by Client,id,t.account->>'ecoOptionID' ) cnt
,case when  reverse(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.account->>'ecoOptionID') FROM 1 for POSITION('_' IN REVERSE(t.account->>'ecoOptionID')) -1)) != t.account->>'seq' 
then 'mismatch'
when  reverse(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.account->>'ecoOptionID') FROM 1 for POSITION('_' IN REVERSE(t.account->>'ecoOptionID')) -1)) = t.account->>'seq' 
then 'match'
else 'N/A'
end seq_id_match 
    from
    eco_val  a,
    jsonb_array_elements(eco_js ::jsonb->'ecoOptions') WITH ORDINALITY AS t (account, rn)
where id = '7193497_1')b where seq_id_match='mismatch')
loop

v_sql :='
update eco_val  set eco_js =
jsonb_set(eco_js ::jsonb,''{ecoOptions,'||rec.ind||',ecoOptionID}'',
''"'||rec.id||'_'||rec.seq||'"'')
where Client='''||rec.Client||''' and id='''||rec.id||'''';
raise info using message := concat('Final query ',v_sql);
execute  v_sql; 
end loop;
end;
$$;
```

The FOR loop will iterate through each index which has a mismatch in the ecoOptionID and replace the value with the concatenation of ID and SEQ.